# Abstract orbits stabilizers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider $D_8$ acting on itself by conjugation. Find orbits and stabilizers for all elements of $D_8$.

$$D_8=\{1,r,r^2,r^3,b,br,br^2,br^3\}$$

So far I have the orbits: {$1$}, {$r^2$}, {$r,r^3$}, {$r^2$}, {$b,br^2$}, and {$br,br^3$}.

Can someone verify this and help me with the stabilizers, thank!

Comment: You got two $\{r^2\}$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the stabilizers, I evaluate some of them by hand. So if we assume $$D_8=\{1,a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b,a^3b\}$$ then according to its relation $a^4=b^2=1,bab=a^{-1}=a^3$ and the definition to stabilizer of an element regarding the action you got, we have:
$$\text{Stab}(1)=D_8\\\text{Stab}(a)=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}\\\text{Stab}(b)=\{1,b,a^2,ba^2\}\\\text{Stab}(a^2)=D_8\\\text{Stab}(ab)=\{1,a^2,ba^{-1},ba\}\\ .\\\ .\\\ .\\ .\\\text{Stab}(a^3b)=\{1,a^2,ba^3,ba\}$$

Comment: Nice work, Babak ;-)

Comment: @Babak S:❁Was excellent✓